# How to check second item in list if it is null to avoid exception

Tags: c#, list

How to check if second item in list is a null  to avoid  `if id < MyList.Count && MyList[id] != null`:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' 
>   Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection.

Comment: Looks like you also need to check if `id + 1 < MyList.Count`.

Comment: Checking for null wont avoid an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.  *Nothing* in the exception text suggests something is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Length()` property in addition to what you are already doing (Assuming `id` is an integer):

```
   if (MyList != null && MyList.Length() >= id && MyList[id + 1] != null || MyList[id + 1] != "")
   {
        Var = MyList[id + 1];                    
   }
```

Depending on what kind of list you have, you may have to use `Count()`:

```
   if (MyList != null && MyList.Count() >= id && MyList[id + 1] != null || MyList[id + 1] != "")
   {
        Var = MyList[id + 1];                    
   }
```

Comment: Since it's called `MyList` I'd guess it's a `List<T>` which doesn't have a `Length` property.  Also you say property, but your using it like a method.

Comment: Of course, and in that case, use `Count()`, which is part of the answer.

Comment: the conditions `MyList[id + 1] != null || MyList[id + 1] != ""` do nothing to address the exception, so they can be securely removed.
`MyList.Length() >= id` contains a typo, for it will throw IndexOutOfBound on the last iteration: it must be `MyList.Length() > id`, same for the List version

Comment: @GoGoLander, it is possible to have an element in the list that is null (or blank). The OP still needs to check for that.

Comment: @matt-spinks It sure is, but it is not the reason of the exception

Comment: Right, I am showing "the fix" added to the OP's code. Not just the fix by itself. That would be confusing.

Comment: I partially agree with you, I'm just looking at the question from a different point of view: put this way, it looks like one have to check for a non-null value of the array element in order to solve a IndexOutOfBound exception, which makes no sense.
That's all I'm saying, no disrespect implied...

Answer (score 1):

It's not a null pointer exception. It's a index out of bounds exception, caused by trying to access an index of MyList that is greater than MyList.length - 1. (Minus one, because arrays start at index 0.)